# If you prestige, do you keep your unlocked tokens?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I want to know if you prestige, do you get to keep the unlocked tokens you have gained?

Comment: In MW3, once you used an Unlock Token, the item stayed unlocked across all prestiges.  I imagine in BO2 it works the same way, but I have yet to take the disc out of the box, so I can't confirm :)

Comment: @agent86 : in BO2, the create a class system is all new, so it doesn't work exactly as in MW3.

Comment: I pretty sure the OP means the non-prestige unlock tokens.  The tokens that you get after gaining a level.

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the unlock tokens you use to unlock guns and perks, then no, they do not persist across prestiges. It is to note that even at max level, there are not enough unlock tokens to unlock every single piece of gear (Perks, Wildcards, Guns, & Equipment.) The exception for this is reaching Prestige Master, when all gear will unlock and you will have access to every item. When you prestige you do get a single 'Prestige unlock' which you can use to do one of 3 things

- Fresh Start: Completely reset all stats and start at level 1
- Unlock Token Reset: Refund all spent unlock tokens, to unlock different gear
- Perma Unlock: Remove an item's level minimum so that on further prestiges you do not have to level up to unlock the item. (Still must be level 4 to unlock Create-A-Class)

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not get to keep the unlock tokens, so make sure you spend them before you prestige.  Once you prestige though, you will get a prestige unlock token, which can permanently unlock a weapon or perk.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: Why would you want to spend all of your unlock tokens before you prestige if you are going to lose all of them (and all of your guns) and have to re-level to get them back?

Comment: @Mondrianaire, you don't really have to, I was just mentioning it so that they don't feel like they were wasted.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep permanent unlock tokens I have 3 currently.

Answer (score -1):

In Black Ops 2, when you prestige, all the guns/perks are locked back. When you reach level 4 and access the "create a class", they're locked (except the ones available at level 4). When you reach the level where it's available, it will automatically unlock and go back to the level it was before you prestiged, so you don't lose the progression, and the equipments you previously unlocked are available.

The only way to have the item unlocked at level 4 is by using a prestige token to permanently unlock the gun/perk (create a class, choose the weapon/perk/equipment and press RB/R1 on XBOX/PS3). It will then be available as soon as you reach level 4 on each prestige. If the gun reaches its max level, you can prestige that gun and send it back to level 1 (main reason is so you can re-earn XP from attachments challenges).

I hope it's clear ! For those of you who may know better, if I'm wrong in some way or if I missed something, please tell me !

---

Edit : you can refer to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ythtuFoM1VE) video for prestige infos !

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about prestige tokens.

Comment: Neither do I ! But maybe your answer is in fact more appropriate, I thought he was asking "do the guns/perks/.. you unlock with a token during your progression are still available once you prestiged ?". The way he used "unlocked tokens" (note the **d** at the end of unlock) made me think he was asking about already used tokens. Really deserves a down vote though ?

Comment: The downvote is because this doesn't answer the question the OP is asking, even if he/she _was_ talking about prestige unlock tokens (which I believe the OP is not).  While informative, I don't think it should be here, as it could be confusing.