# Prestige unlock token and Prestige reward

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Do you lose your prestige unlock token if you select a prestige reward and vice versa?
A couple of friends have been telling me that you do.

**When you prestige, can you get a prestige reward AND a permanent unlock, or is it just one of the two?**

Comment: Have a look a [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93627/if-you-prestige-do-you-keep-your-unlocked-tokens), maybe it contains your answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can save your permanent unlock tokens. I have three right now. The other part of the answer is correct - you lose the reward if not used.

Comment: Your answer directly contradicts the established answer; do you have a source for your information?

Comment: @fbueckert This answer was posted a long time after i asked the question. By then, I have tested this out.

Answer (score 2):

You get a permanent unlock token and a choice of the three prestige rewards per prestige level. However, if you prestige before you use up either the reward or the token, you lose them.